# Using FPDF's WriteHTML() in header/footer

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to use the writeHTML script (here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script41.php) as well as the header and footer from tutorial 6 (here: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm).

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once('WriteHTML.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
     // Page footer
     function Footer()
     {

     $this->SetY(-30);
     $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);     
     $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo(),0,0,'C');
     $html = '<p>some HTML</p>';

     $this->WriteHTML($html);
     }

     // Some more functions... header, PrintChapter etc... 
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetTitle($title);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->PrintChapter(1,'A RUNAWAY REEF','test.txt'); // print text file content
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

`Call to undefined method PDF::WriteHTML() in /path/to/test2.php on line 15`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extend `PDF_HTML`, not `FPDF` as `WriteHTML` is part of `PDF_HTML`.

If you want inheritance to work, you always need to extend the classes you want to use. Let say you want to extend `PDF_Index`, you still need `WriteHTML` in the inheritance somewhere.

Perhaps

```
PDF extends PDF_Index
```

and

```
PDF_Index extends PDF_HTML
```

Or,

```
PDF_HTML extends PDF_Index
```

But you need both in the chain to make it work.

If you don't put both in the inheritance chain, then you will not use the available functions from the branch you are not using.

```
       ---> PDF_HTML
     /
FPDF ----> PDF_Index ----> PDF
```

The, the function in PDF_HTML will not be available to PDF

Comment: That works, however I can't seem to understand the inheritance chain works with more scripts. Adding the bookmark & index scripts, if I update my code to `class PDF extends PDF_Index` for example, `WriteHTML($html);` stops working again...

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation. Works like a charm. I now have each script extend the previous one, I hope I can just keep track with all the included scripts :)